# If DataKeyNames is set to a field not defined as a primary key, then…

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, gridview

1) I noticed that if I set *GridView.DataKeyNames* to a field that actually isn’t defined as primary key in data source, data source control ( or perhaps GridView?) will somehow know that field set in *DataKeyNames* isn’t really a primary key. I became aware of that fact when I opened  *Configure the Select Statement* window ( via  *GridView’s Smart Tasks pop up --> Configure Data Source --> Configure the Select Statement window --> Advanced*) and window had both radio buttons disabled.

a) So how did Asp.Net “figure it out” that field set in *DataKeyNames* is not actually a primary key?

b) Also, shouldn’t it be up to programmer to set *DataKeyNames* to whatever field she chooses to, even if that field is not defined as primary key in a data source?

thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the purpose of the DataKeyNames property is to uniquely identify each and every data row in your data set. For that, ASP.NET needs to make 100% sure it's really truly a uniquely identifying column (or set of columns) that you provide, and the only one that can be truly checked is the primary key of a table - this will always be uniquely identifying a row (that's the very definition of a primary key).

I guess that's the reason that ASP.NET insists on the primary key for the DataKeyNames - any other column (or set of columns) can't really be checked for validity - so it's better to refuse them rather than running into the problems if it's not a uniquely identifying key.....

Marc

Comment: May I also ask:A) I assume Asp.Net can only check if field truly uniquely identifies a row when using SqlDataSource control?! But can Asp.Net also somehow check for uniqueness when using ObjectDataSource control?  
B) I assume Asp.Net "asked" Sql server whether a field is really a primary key?

Comment: ASP.NET can definitely check for primary keys when using a SQL data source, or an ADO.NET DataSet. Not sure about the ObjectDataSource, though.